# Add a Default Item at last position of DataList - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

You can create a DataList easily in asp.net, I need to add a default item at last position of Datalist, for example an item named "Add new Item", if Datalist is empty I can only see this default item if not I see it in last position. Hope I'm clear enough. Is this possible? if yes, HOW?

Comment: Yes, it is possible!

Comment: OK, how? can you give me an example of code :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're data binding your DataList, you just need to add "Add New Item" to your data source before calling DataBind on your DataList.  I don't know what your data source is but the logic should be similar to whatever you're using.  If you're binding to a DataTable you will need to make sure that the sort makes your "Add New Item" entry be the last one.  You may need to add a sort column or something that you give your own incrementing id to and sort based on that column.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
            values.Add("Item 1");
            values.Add("Item 2");
            values.Add("Add New Item");
            DataList dataList = new DataList();
            dataList.DataSource = values;
            dataList.DataBind();
```

Comment: The problem is that Default Item has a different structure than Item templates. For example it contains an image and a button and a drop down, but item templates are only some labels.

Comment: You should be able to just statically put it in the '<FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>' if I recall correctly then.